# Find a way to don't match urls containing @ in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex for validation of urls. But I don't want to match urls containing the character "@". How can I solve that?

```
regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can always first check if your url contains `@` using `indexOf()`, a string method. If it returns a number other than `-1`, your url contains `@`. If it doesn't, proceed using your regex.

**Edit**: you can use this code:

```
if( myString.indexOf('@') == -1 && myString.match(regexp)) { 
    return true; 
} 
else { 
    return false; 
}
```

Which can be further shortened to:

```
return myString.indexOf('@') == -1 && myString.match(myString);
```

Thanks goes to @idealmachine for providing this code faster than me.

Comment: +1 for not extending the regex to an even less readable mess.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of this? Here is my code:

regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

if(myString.match(regexp)){
 return true;
    } else {
 return false;
}

Comment: An example would be: `return myString.indexOf('@') == -1 && regexp.test(myString);`

Answer (score 0):

That should do:

```
regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?[^\/:\s]+(:[0-9]+)?(\/[^@]*)?/;
```